# pydev module import vs console for ROS

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pydev, ros

I am currently trying to use pydev for my ROS project (I am using pydev because I use eclipse for c++) Now I have some issues with importing some modules. 
The current structure looks like this:

```
src
   package_name
      __init__.py
      src
         __init__.py
         package_name
            my_file.py
            __init__.py
      scripts
         my_module.py
         __init__.py
```

I used the catkin_ws as my project root wth the src folder as the sourcefolder for pydev. When I want to import a module e.g. my_module from my_file I have to use (that's what eclipse says)

```
from package_name.scripts.my_module import XYZ
```

This works fine if I am running my_file in pydev but it does not work from the console (e.g. rosrun or python3 my_file.py). How would I have to import my_module in this case and how does pydev recognize this as correct??

Another thing when I try to import my_module from another python script in the scripts folder I would assume that using

```
from my_module import XYZ
```

would work fine ( it does using the console as well as using pydev run) but eclipse still marks it as an error. How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the wrong folder is set as the source folder for Python code.

You probably have `/src` as the source folder and you should probably have `/src/package_name/src` and `src/scripts` set in the PYTHONPATH -- Still, note that I'm not completely sure as the structure of the package seems a bit strange... for instance, why do you have an `__init__.py` right under the `/src` folder? (that seems wrong...)

Note: source folders are the folders added to the `PYTHONPATH`. See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for details.

Comment: Thanks yes this was the issue. However, I had to implement an additional setup.py file for ros... http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile